Semantic equivalence between mathematical proofs
Sometimes, we recognize two proofs of the same claim to be the "same" proof. In some cases, this sameness is obvious -- for example, the proofs that $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ are irrational are the same because they are essentially special cases of the general result that $\sqrt{n}$ for $n$ squarefree is irrational. Perhaps more generally if I imagine that I am using a treelike or daglike proof system, that "sameness" of proofs could correspond to there existing a nontrivial isomorphism of the trees or dags representing the proofs (and perhaps if a nontrivial homomorphism existed, I could imagine the proofs being equivalent "modulo" certain steps/inferences). A notion like this might suffice to define a kind of "syntactic" equivalence between proofs.
However, I have also been thinking about a more nebulous kind of "semantic" equivalence between proofs. This kind of equivalence might even put proofs of different statements into the same equivalence class. For instance, consider the following proof about temporal modal logic (you do not need to know temporal modal logic to follow the example):

In this problem, we are asked to show that $(\mathcal{I}, r, m) \models \Box \Diamond \varphi$ exactly if the set $\{m'' \mid (\mathcal{I}, r, m')\models 
    \varphi\}$ is infinite, for $m' \geq m$.
Suppose that $(\mathcal{I}, r, m) \models \Box \Diamond \varphi$. Then, for all $m' \geq m$, we have that $(\mathcal{I}, r, m')\models \Diamond \varphi$, meaning that for
every $m'$, we may find some $m'' \geq m'$ such that $(\mathcal{I}, r, m'')\models \varphi$. Now suppose for the sake of contradiction that
$\{m'' \mid (\mathcal{I}, r, m')\models \varphi\}$ is a finite set. Then, the set contains a maximal element $M$ such that $(\mathcal{I}, r, M')
\not \models \varphi$ for all $M' > M$. However, by assumption, we must have $(\mathcal{I}, r, M') \models \varphi$ for some $M' > M$, and
thus by contradiction we conclude that the set $\{m' \mid (\mathcal{I}, r, m'')\models \varphi\}$ must be infinite.
Now, conversely, suppose that $S := \{m' \mid (\mathcal{I}, r, m')\models \varphi\}$ is an infinite set. Then, for every $m'$ in the set, we may
find an element $m''$ also in the set such that $m'' \geq m'$, as $\{m'' \mid (\mathcal{I}, r, m')\models \varphi\}$, as $S$ is indexed by the
natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$. Therefore, if we fix some $m'$, we have $(\mathbb{I}, r, m'') \models \varphi$ for some $m'' \geq m'$. Then, iterating
this argument for every $m_i \in S$ for $i \in \mathbb{N}$, we see that $(I, r, m) \models \Diamond \varphi$ for each $m' \in S$, and since
we may always find $m'' \geq m'$ such that $(I, r, m'') \models \varphi$, we have $(I, r, m) \models \Box \Diamond \varphi$, as required.
This completes the proof that that $(\mathcal{I}, r, m) \models \Box \Diamond \varphi$ exactly if the set $\{m' \mid (\mathcal{I}, r, m')\models 
\varphi\}$ is infinite, for $m' \geq m$.

This is obviously a proof by contradiction, but I think our analysis can get more specific than that. In this proof, we assume the finitude of a specific object (defined by a certain clear property), then show that this assumption allows us to constructively define an object that violates this property. Conceptually, at least half of the proof works very similar to the proof of the infinitude of primes -- for that is also a proof by contradiction done by assuming that finitude holds. Obviously many other proofs by contradiction share this structure, and in algebra, we have examples of constructive proofs that seem to follow certain patterns as well -- hence us being able to define objects like the free functor to "parametrize" the fundamental semantics behind these constructions.
What I wonder is if there is a semantic way to look at "types" of proof -- proofs by contradiction, proofs by enumeration, proofs by construction, etc... with respect to their fundamental semantic "gestural" components. It is OK if the existing efforts on this matter are confined to proofs formulated (implicitly) following some specific logic. I know that there is a paper of Baez formulating a category of propositions with proofs as morphisms between them -- perhaps this category of morphisms is what I've been talking about for this whole post? In any case I'd appreciate seeing if anything substantial comes of this question, and if there are any references where I can read about this topic more.

Do you know about proof-relevant logic, e.g. the Brouwer–Heyting–Kolmogorov interpretation, or Martin-Löf type theory?

I'm aware of treating proofs as terms of some type, but I haven't seen much analysis done in the specific direction I mention above in that vein

Note that the proof by contradiction can be replaced by induction in this example. You don't need a contradiction to show things are infinite.

That's true, and to me, that would yield a semantically distinct proof @ChristopherKing. It wouldn't be "the same" as the infinitude of primes proof in that case.
